# Error while executing buildear in UNIX

Tags: java, unix, tibco

The buildear command is as follows :

```
    buildear -s -x /Archive/My_App.archive -o /app/Script_Sql/Jen_Workspace/My_App.ear -p /app/Script_Sql/Jen_Workspace/My_App
```

The EAR is getting created but i am getting below error :

```
    Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException:
    No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getScreenSize(HeadlessToolkit.java:261)
    at com.extensibility.rock.l.doGetWorkArea(Platform.java:197)
    at com.extensibility.rock.l.a(Platform.java:193)
    at com.extensibility.rock.u.<clinit>(Screen.java:52)
```

I did read about Java's "headless" installation capabilty wherein it allows installation without GUI/AWT libraries (please correct me if I am wrong). I tried setting the value of DISPLAY (export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0) but didn't work. Please suggest any solution for this.
FYI - I don't have root or sudo privileges on the UNIX server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `buildear` utility requires an X server to be executed.

To work around this, try adding `java.property.java.awt.headless=true` in the `bwengine.tra`. If it doesn't do the trick, you might want to ask your sys admin to install and configure [Xvfb](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml), a virtual X server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Nicholas. But it didnt work. If you are from TIBCO background, will this error affect my EAR ? or will it affect my processes in any way ?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not really surprised. Now you are left with the Xvfb option. This is what most people do to overcome this error (unless you can have an actual X server set up on the UNIX server, of course).

Comment: To answer your question, this error only occurs when trying to build an EAR using the `buildear` executable (or when using `buildlibrary` to build a DTL) in a headless environment. It is not a runtime error and won't affect your processes at all.